# Android : How to store a generated ID and recall it the next app run?

Tags: android

Every time my app starts an ID is generated by my program. Since each time it generates a different ID , I want to save the ID somewhere before exiting the program so I can use it again when the program runs later.

Sample ID : 125469

Note : I rather to not save it in file but some else.

Comment: use shared Preference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even a better solution would be to use **GreenDAO** here are some examples

https://github.com/greenrobot/greenDAO

https://github.com/octa-george/Android-GreenDao-Sample

```
GreenDAO is a light & fast ORM solution for Android that maps objects to SQLite databases. Being highly optimized for Android, greenDAO offers great performance and consumes minimal memory.
```

You only need the greendao jar

```
public class MyDaoGenerator {

      public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
      Schema schema = new Schema(1, "ro.octa.greendaosample.dao");
      createSchema(schema);
      new DaoGenerator().generateAll(schema, "C:/GreenDaoSchema");
}

private static void createSchema(Schema schema) {

     Entity user = schema.addEntity("DBUser");
     user.addIdProperty().primaryKey().autoincrement();
     user.addStringProperty("email").notNull().unique();
     user.addStringProperty("password").notNull();

}
```

After a few lines of code you have the model generated for autoincrement id, email and password.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `SharedPreferences` or you can use `SQLite` database for storing purposes.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like that:

```
private SharedPreferences prefs;

...
...
private void initializeFromPreference() {
prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
myId = prefs.getInt("myId", myId );
}
...
...
public void onDestroy() {
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
editor.putInt("myId", myId );
editor.commit();
super.onDestroy();
}
```

i wouldnt use a database for a single value, `Sharedpreferences` is a good way to do so

Answer (score 0):

You can Use SharedPreferences to store your id

```
 SharedPreferences prefs=this.getSharedPreferences("yourPrefsKey", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

       Editor edit=prefs.edit();

       //to store value
       edit.putInt("Your Id Name", Id Value).commit();

       //to get value

       int id=prefs.getInt("Your Id Name", 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the simple way, I can think of :)

```
    public static SharedPreferences sharedpreferences;
    sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences("MyIds", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    if (sharedpreferences.contains("id"))
    {
       String id = sharedpreferences.getString("id", "");
       // *Use existing id and enjoy* ;)
    }
    else{

            // *Generate New ID (yourID)*
            Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
            editor.putString("id", yourID);
            editor.commit();
    }
```